# Django | no such table: users_profile Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

help me find a bug please.
I am migrating my project from sqlite to mysql.
When I create a superuser, I manage to connect to the database and create a user line in it, but I get an error when I open the website page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndgas.png)

I think the creation is sent correctly, but further queries are sent from sqlite.
How can this be fixed, what is my mistake?

Also, the sqlite database is automatically created (empty) - probably trying to search in it.

I've already deleted all the migration files and the database itself, and then:
python manage.py makemigrations users
python manage.py migrate

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'bdname',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '000.000.000.000',
    'PORT': ''
    }
}

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://new.lk.positron.pro/login/

Django Version: 3.2.14
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'feedback.apps.FeedbackConfig',
 'billing.apps.BillingConfig',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: users_profile) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 170, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 373, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 400, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 202, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 42, in sensitive_variables_wrapper
    return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 76, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 42, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 45, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /login/
Exception Value: no such table: users_profile
```

Next, from the settings

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['*']
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'users.Profile'
BASE_DIR    
PosixPath('/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/public_html/beetle')
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': PosixPath('/home/c/xxx/new.lk.positron.pro/public_html/beetle/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,



> ignored_wrapper_args   (False,  {'connection':
> <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.DatabaseWrapper object at
> 0x7f8e98d017b8>,   'cursor':
> <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at
> 0x7f8e97642f28>}) params   ('r.kirzhanov@albato.ru',) self    
> <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7f8e97642f28>
> sql    ('SELECT "users_profile"."id", "users_profile"."password", ' 
> '"users_profile"."last_login", "users_profile"."is_superuser", ' 
> '"users_profile"."email".....
```

settings.py:
.
.
.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

from django.conf import settings


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = '***'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['***']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'feedback.apps.FeedbackConfig',
    'billing.apps.BillingConfig',

    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'beetle.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'beetle.wsgi.application'

'''
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
'''


DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'bdname',
    'USER': 'name',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '111.111.111.111',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


#DATE_FORMAT = ( ( 'd-m-Y' ))
#DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( ('%d-%m-%Y'),)
#DATETIME_FORMAT = (( 'd-m-Y H:i' ))
#DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (('%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'),)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = False


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'main-index'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Profile'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

What other information can I provide?

Comment: Please post all code and error traceback as text, not as images. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: @AlexK
Did I send correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sqlite database configuration from your settings.py
Only leave the configuration to your MySQL.

EDIT: Now that i can read your settings.py i found the following code configuration for the sqlite3 database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

And you have your MySQL configuration commented with the triple quote.

```
'''
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'bdname',
    'USER': 'name',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '111.111.111.111',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
'''
```

Switch it to comment the sqlite configuration and leave the MySQL as:

```
'''
   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
'''
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'bdname',
    'USER': 'name',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '111.111.111.111',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this solves the problem, my best regards.

Comment: This is all I have

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'bdname',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '000.000.000.000',
    'PORT': ''
    }
}

Comment: No other settings

Comment: Is that your full settings.py file in your question? if not, could you add a the full code of the file please, it may be helpful if not for me editing my answer but for future answers.

Comment: I added the settings.py file

Comment: The strangest thing is that I was able to create my user entry.
But when I use it, it sends a query from sqlite

Comment: And the empty sqlite database is created only afterwards...Not after the migration

Comment: This is not the cause of the error, unfortunately :(
The triple quotes were added when I switched between databases. But at the time of the test they were not used

Comment: The string is created on mysql...
But when I open the site, for some reason sqlite

Comment: So you alredy deleted the whole " DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }" block and it appeared back again in your file?

Comment: Oh you mean you put it back because MySQL didn't work.

Comment: Wich modules did you install to use MySQL with django?

Comment: asgiref==3.4.1
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
Django==3.2.14
djangorestframework==3.13.1
idna==3.3
mysqlclient==2.1.1
Pillow==8.4.0
pytz==2022.1
requests==2.27.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing_extensions==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.11

Comment: Yes, you're right! I deleted it because my mysql is not working :(But that's definitely not the reason.

Comment: Or do you mean mysql-connector-python?